# Angular campos dinámicos con ngmodel

Tags: angular

Hola a todos tengo una tabla en mi html en la cual al presionar un botón de agregar fila se agrega una nueva fila a mi tabla angular, todo esto con un `*ngFor`.

Lo que necesito realizar es que al crear una nueva fila mi ngModel sea dinámico para poder agregar luego los campos a la base de datos.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let t of valores, let i=index">
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tratamiento_{{i}}" placeholder="Tratamiento{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tratamientosIngresoMedico.tratamiento"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="desayuno_{{i}}" placeholder="Desayuno{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tratamientosIngresoMedico.desayuno"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="almuerzo_{{i}}" placeholder="Almuerzo{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tratamientosIngresoMedico.almuerzo"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="merienda_{{i}}" placeholder="Merienda{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tratamientosIngresoMedico.merienda"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="cena_{{i}}" placeholder="Cena{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tratamientosIngresoMedico.cena"></td>
 </tr>
```

Boton el cual me agrega una nueva fila

```
<button type="button" (click)="addtable()" class="btn btn-add btn-sm btn-block mb-3"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Agregar nuevo tratamiento</button>
```

y el TS

```
  addtable() {
    this.numerotablas = this.numerotablas + 1;
    this.valores = Array(this.numerotablas).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
  }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar un formulario reactivo? Crear uno dinámico es mucho más sencillo que con ngModel

Answer (score 3):

Una de las mejores formas que yo he podido hacer eso es con indices.

Aqui muestra un input de forma dinamica en el cual al dar Add lo que genera un push al arreglo:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app",
  template: `
  <form #formRef="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let word2 of words2; let in=index" class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="words2[in].value" name="name{{in}}" class="form-control" #name="ngModel" required />
          <!--<p [hidden]="words2[in].value">Field is required</p>
          {{formRef.form.name1}}-->
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <button [disabled]="!formRef.form.valid" (click)="add()">Add input</button>
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  {{words2 | json}}
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  words2 = [{value: 'word1'}, {value: 'word2'}, {value: 'word3'}, {value: ''}];

  add() {
    this.words2.push({value: 'gsre'});
  }
}
```

Revisa este ejemplo a ver si te es util:

```
https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/ukV3PZ
```

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/191011)

Comment: Ok, es la primera vez que quiero aportar, ya modifique.

Comment: Excelente! :), esto ayuda que tu respuesta también sea bien recibida !

Comment: Seguro gracias, espero que sirva.